# Is it possible to set Calibre Editor to automatically backup a book file before modifying it?

Tags: epub, calibre, editing

Pretty much as the title says, is it possible to set Calibre to automatically create a backup copy of a given `.epub` file before editing it?

When experimenting, it would be handy to keep the original file untouched.

Comment: Frankly I haven't used the Calibre editor, but I would find hard to believe that it wouldn't. When doing conversions, it usually creates separate directories for source and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Calibre's developer, he said that it is not possible and that he doesn't find such feature useful, so he is not willing to implement it.

Comment: Calibre has a checkpoint feature (**Edit > Create checkpoint**) that you could use for backups. Simply assign it a keyboard shortcut and press it before major edits.